# What happens to unsynced changes when the parent repos of a github fork is deleted?

Tags: git, github

From this github [help page](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility/)

> When you delete a public repository, one of the existing public forks is chosen to be the new parent repository. All other repositories are forked off of this new parent and subsequent pull requests go to this new parent.

What happens if the chosen fork is some commits behind the parent, will the chosen fork automatically receive a pull request for the changes?

Comment: No. Pull requests always have to be initiated explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happens if the chosen fork is some commits behind the parent, will the chosen fork automatically receive a pull request for the changes?

If you mean "behind the parent who just got deleted", no since it is just deleted.
It does not appear that the new parent benefits from a `fetch old_parent` before `old_parent` is deleted (if that was the case, you would still see the old pull requests submitted to that old repo as remote branches in the new repo)

That is why the help page says: "**subsequent** pull requests go to this new parent."

As the [OP mozey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639133/mozey) summarizes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497029/what-happens-to-unsynced-changes-when-the-parent-repos-of-a-github-fork-is-delet/38498895#comment65519509_38498895):

> Unsynced commits to the old_parent repos will then be lost

Comment: Unsynced commits to the `old_parent` repos will then be lost

Comment: @mozey Indeed. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.